# Issues printing email content sent with python in Android

Tags: android, python, email, jakarta-mail

I'm making an android application that has to take an email, which has been sent via a python script to a gmail account, and search the subject and message body for certain phrases. I haven't had any problem setting up the email services (I'm using the smtp library to send in python, and javamail IMAP to read in android studio), or sending and opening the emails themselves. I've also been able to search the subject for whatever phrase or character I want, but when I wrote some test code to try to print the message body, nothing gets printed. I've checked that the email is actually formatted properly by opening gmail in a browser, and the content is definitely there, but when I use javamail's getContent() and convert it to a string, nothing gets printed. I know that getContent() can be weird because it returns an object, but since the message I'm sending is just text, with no images or attachments, I thought just using toString() would work.

Here's the applicable code (with usernames and passwords removed)

Python:

```
message = """From:  Sender <send address>
To: Receiver <receive address>
Subject: test

test message
"""
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login(username, password)
smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
```

Android (I've skipped all the login and session code, because I know it works)

```
Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
System.out.println("Reading messages...");
    for(Message message:messages) {
        for (Address a: message.getFrom()){
            System.out.println("From:" + a);
            System.out.println("Title: " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(message.getContent().toString());
            System.out.println("---");
        }
    }
```

Here's the printout in android studio when the message is opened:

```
I/System.out: From:Sender <send address>
I/System.out: Title: test
I/System.out: ---
```

So it just prints as if the content is null, but it is definitely there when I open the email in a browser. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with message.getContent(), but everything I've looked up and tried has the same result. Any advice on how to properly print and store the content as a string, or properly use getContent() would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

EDIT: Updated javamail, now having classDef error at getContent() line, and am not sure how to solve.

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.5
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method javax.mail.Session com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.getSession() would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in javax.mail.Service
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 71.53.10.66 m64mb113652972qkl
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! m64mb113652972qkl
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: OAUTHBEARER
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user=********, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK ******** authenticated (Success)
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT APPENDLIMIT=35882577 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS
A2 OK Success
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
A3 SELECT Inbox
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing \*)] Flags permitted.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1] UIDs valid.
* 8 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT 1204] Predicted next UID.
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 84995]
A3 OK [READ-WRITE] Inbox selected. (Success)
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.mail.internet.MimePartDataSource>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMultipartDataSource>
I/System.out: Reading messages...
A4 FETCH 1 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
* 1 FETCH (RFC822.SIZE 3287 INTERNALDATE "03-Jun-2016 02:10:05 +0000" ENVELOPE ("Thu, 02 Jun 2016 19:10:04 -0700 (PDT)" "test" ((NIL NIL "network.test.recv" "gmail.com")) ((NIL NIL "network.test.recv" "gmail.com")) ((NIL NIL "network.test.recv" "gmail.com")) ((NIL NIL "network.test.send" "gmail.com")) NIL NIL NIL "<5750e6fc.335a8c0a.86b06.2ffb@mx.google.com>"))
A4 OK Success
I/System.out: From:*********
I/System.out: Title: test
A5 FETCH 1 (BODYSTRUCTURE)
* 1 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE ("TEXT" "PLAIN" NIL NIL NIL "7BIT" 14 1 NIL NIL NIL))
A5 OK Success
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler>

             --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-220
               Process: com.example.thecortex.myapplication, PID: 24663
               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler
                               at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getDataHandler(MimeMessage.java:1422)
                               at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getDataHandler(IMAPMessage.java:776)
                               at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1454)
                               at com.example.thecortex.myapplication.MainActivity$1$override.run(MainActivity.java:50)
                               at com.example.thecortex.myapplication.MainActivity$1$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                               at com.example.thecortex.myapplication.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:0)
                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup, force false
DEBUG IMAPS: close folder
A6 UNSELECT
A6 OK Returned to authenticated state. (Success)
DEBUG IMAPS: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
A7 LOGOUT
* BYE LOGOUT Requested
A7 OK 73 good day (Success)
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup done
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup, not connected
```

Comment: There's two lines missing from your output so something is definitely wrong.  What do you see when you turn on [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug)?  The getContent line should at least be printing something.  I don't understand how that line could be skipped entirely and then go to the line that prints the dashes.  Can you run in a debugger and step through that line?

Comment: I added session.setDebug(True); right after creating the session in the code, but there was no additional output in logcat or on the android debugging console, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Also, I noticed when I run the app, it seems to hang for a split second when it should be printing the getContent line to the log, as if something was being processed, but its not throwing any exceptions or printing what it's supposed to obviously.

Comment: You can try using the Session.setDebugOut method to redirect the debug output to somewhere else, to make sure you can see it.  Also, you're using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#JavaMail_for_Android) release, right?

Comment: So there's been an interesting development. I was able to get the debug printouts like you suggested, and I realized that the javamail version I had was out of date, so I created a new application with the same email code as before, but with the latest jar from the link you posted, and now the code crashes when it gets to the getContent() line. I added the exception trace and the debug printout as an edit to the original post. I've looked up the error I'm getting, but what I've read has gone over my head a little, so if you could point me in a direction to start, I'd be grateful.

Comment: It looks like some sort of classpath problem.  Perhaps you have a mix of different versions of the JavaMail classes?  What are all the jar files you're including in your application?  Does more than one of them have the javax.mail classes in them?  Is the javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler class included in your application package?  Are you using any tools to "obfuscate" your code or to strip out "unneeded" classes?

Comment: So I finally found a workaround, instead of using the jar files as a library I'm compiling the Javamail stuff directly from a url (which is actually the way you're supposed to do it for Android, I didn't realize that until I did some digging), then because getContent() just absolutely refuses to work properly on text for some reason I hunted until I found a way to print the plain text/html content using an input stream/buffered reader. Long story short, the code's not pretty, but it works now so thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you explain further, in case others have this problem?  What does "directly from a url" mean?  In what ways was getContent() not working?

Comment: Heres a link to the code i added to the gradle file to compile the javamail library from a repository https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Android. That solved the classpath problem, as for what exactly was wrong with getContent() I was never able to figure out. The debug printout showed it was fetching the correct information (the content of the email) but it wasn't being returned. So, i abandoned getContent () for text/html emails and used a similar approach to the code here (sorry I dont have my code): http://tutorialspointexamples.com/javamail-api-receiving-fetching-email-attachment/

Answer (score 0):

I had also some problems in the past and it was due to a strange indentation. If you look below the From/TO/Subjct has no spaces from beginning of the line.
Taking from one def:

```
def mail_form(): 
   ......
   message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, "; ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
....
smtp.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
```

Afterwards I am using the smtp.sendmail(FROM, TO, message). The indentation is really relevant and I am substituting the FROM and TO, SUBJECT and TEXT already in the message. I hope this can help a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I went back into the python code and set it up how you suggested, but unfortunately it didn't change anything. The android code is still printing null when it tries to get the content of the email, but it still appears to be formatted correctly. I also set up some exception handling on both sides, but neither are giving any errors, the only abnormal issue is the null print. I suspect the problem is with how I'm using getContent(), and I'm looking up more info about it now but most of it hasn't been very helpful. If you have any other advice I'd appreciate it.